# I require assistance in understanding what's wrong with my code (if statements)

Tags: python, eclipse, if-statement

I'm not sure what I did wrong in this code, but for some reason, Eclipse keeps on telling me that the if statement is just bad.  I'm not sure why, when I look at the examples, it looked fine to me.

```
penny = .01
nickel = .05
dime = .1
quarter = .25
print("Enter how many coins you want to use to make a dollar.")
e_pen = int(input("Enter the amount of pennies you want: "))
e_nic = int(input("Enter the amount of nickels you want: "))
e_dim = int(input("Enter the amount of dimes you want: "))
e_qua = int(input("Enter the amount of quarters you want: "))

doll = float((e_pen * penny) + (e_nic * nickel) + (e_dim *dime) + (e_qua * quarter))
if doll > 1    # every conditional needs a : per the answer below
    print("The total value is greater than 1 dollar.")  # notice the indentation
else          # same here
   print("Try again.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If statements require a colon and proper indentation, see:

```
if doll > 1:
    print("blah")
else:
    Print ("Try again")
```

Note, the indentation is 4 spaces.